# Generating XML Documents from XML Schemas

Tags: c#, xsd

I'm using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx) xml sample generator to create a sample of the following XSD files:

Main XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xs:schema            xmlns:pur="http://NamespaceTest.com/Purchase"
                      xmlns:cmn="http://NamespaceTest.com/CommonTypes"
                      xmlns:cust="http://NamespaceTest.com/CustomerTypes"
                      targetNamespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/Purchase"
                      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                      elementFormDefault="qualified">
        <xs:import schemaLocation="test2.xsd"
                            namespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/CommonTypes" />
        <xs:import schemaLocation="test.xsd"
                            namespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/CustomerTypes" />
        <xs:element name="CustomerDetails" type="cust:CustomerType" />
</xs:schema>
```

Customer XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:cmn="http://NamespaceTest.com/CommonTypes"
                      targetNamespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/CustomerTypes"
                      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                      elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:import schemaLocation="test2.xsd"
                      namespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/CommonTypes" />
            <xs:complexType name="CustomerType">
                <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="DeliveryAddress" type="cmn:AddressType" />
                        <xs:element name="BillingAddress" type="cmn:AddressType" />
                </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Common Types XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/CommonTypes"
                      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                      elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:complexType name="AddressType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Line1" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="Line2" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The result of the following commands is a xml with a namespace prefix I don't expected, namely `xmlns="http://NamespaceTest.com/CustomerTypes` instead of `xmlns="http://NamespaceTest.com/CommenTypes` for the delivery address and billing address:

```
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, settings);
            XmlQualifiedName qname = new XmlQualifiedName("CustomerDetails", @"http://www.test.de");
            XmlSampleGenerator generator = new XmlSampleGenerator(@"C:\Users\test.xsd", qname);
            generator.WriteXml(writer);
            Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
```

Result xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<CustomerDetails xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://NamespaceTest.com/Purchase">
  <Name xmlns="http://NamespaceTest.com/CustomerTypes">Name1</Name>
  <DeliveryAddress xmlns="http://NamespaceTest.com/CustomerTypes">
    <Line1 xmlns="http://NamespaceTest.com/CommonTypes">Line11</Line1>
    <Line2 xmlns="http://NamespaceTest.com/CommonTypes">Line21</Line2>
  </DeliveryAddress>
  <BillingAddress xmlns="http://NamespaceTest.com/CustomerTypes">
    <Line1 xmlns="http://NamespaceTest.com/CommonTypes">Line11</Line1>
    <Line2 xmlns="http://NamespaceTest.com/CommonTypes">Line21</Line2>
  </BillingAddress>
</CustomerDetails>
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  The generated XML is valid per the schema you gave the generator, is it not?

Comment: To put Charles Mager's comment another way:  why are you expecting a particular namespace prefix? And why do you believe the generator is wrong if it uses a different one?

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen I dont belive the generator is wrong. What I want to do is to explain the generator to tell the generator to use namespace which I use in the document.